# Consumption CAPM and compounded risk free rate

Tags: consumption, risk

I am studying consumption CAPM and trying to prove, assuming lognormal consumption growth one can show that the continuously compounded risk-free rate is:
[image]

Answer (score 2):

This is a one-line calculation under standard CRRA-lognormal assumptions (see, for example, also [this question](https://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/8397/log-normality-assumption-in-consumption-based-asset-pricing?rq=1)).

By CRRA and lognormal consumption growth assumptions, the pricing kernel is
$$
\frac{\rho u'(c_{t+1})}{u'(c_t)} = \rho (\frac{c_{t+1}}{c_t})^{-\gamma}
$$
where $\log \frac{c_{t+1}}{c_t} \stackrel{d}{\sim} \mathcal{N}(\mu, \sigma^2)$. So the risk-free rate $r$ is given by
$$
e^{-r} = E[\rho (\frac{c_{t+1}}{c_t})^{-\gamma}] = \rho e^{-\gamma \mu + \frac12 \gamma^2 \sigma^2},
$$
which implies
$$
r = - \log \rho + \gamma \mu - \frac12 \gamma^2 \sigma^2,
$$
with the three terms reflecting time preference, intertemporal substitution, and precautionary saving, respectively.

In your quoted notation, the first difference $\Delta \log c_{t+1} = \log c_{t+1} - \log c_t = \log \frac{c_{t+1}}{c_t}$.